# JQuery Resizable And Draggable

Tags: jquery

I have an iFrame and I want the user to be able to grab one side of it and drag it to resize it. I don't want it to resize realtime, but rather use an indicator line and when the user releases, it'll resize.

```
$('.Myclass').draggable({ 
    iframeFix: true, 
    containment: "#canvass",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        MyFunction($(this));
    } 
});

$('.Myclass').resizable({
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        MyFunction($(this)); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is not really phrased as a question, and your current code needs to be included for correction, since this isn't a forum which creates code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Jquery links

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

1. jquery code

   $(document).ready(function () {

   ```
       //----------Video--------
       $('.video').draggable({ iframeFix: true, containment: "#canvass", scroll: false, stop: function (event, ui) { SetVideoPostion($(this)); } });
       $('.video').resizable({ stop: function (e, ui) { SetVideoPostion($(this)); } });


   });

   function SetVideoPostion(ctrl) {

       var videoId = ctrl.attr('id');
       var width = ctrl.css('width');
       var height = ctrl.css('height');
       var index = ctrl.css('z-index');
       var left = ctrl.css('left');
       var top = ctrl.css('top');
       var position = ctrl.css('position');
       var style = 'style=" padding:10px;  cursor: move; z-index:' + index + ';left:' + left + '; top:' + top + ';position:' + position + '; width:' + width + '; height:' + height + ';"';
       $("#Position").text(style);
   }
   ```
2. Add Html Tag

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="video" style="display: block; padding: 2px; background-color: #000; height: 200px; width: 400px; padding: 10px; cursor: move;">

    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UMciMQ-jipk" frameborder="0" class="frame"></iframe>

</div>
```